# element.style.display='none' is not working

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function nameofmonth(month)
 {  
 var monthname=new  Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
  return monthname[month]
}  
 function monthdays(month,year)
 {
  var daysofmonth=new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)
  if(year%4==0)
  daysofmonth[1]=29  
  return daysofmonth[month]   
  }
 function close(){

 document.getElementById("container").style.display='none'
 }

 function table()
  {
   var now=new Date()
   var hour=now.getHours()
   var minute=now.getMinutes()
   var second=now.getSeconds()
   var date=now.getDate()
   var month=now.getMonth() 
   var year=now.getFullYear()
   now.setFullYear(year,month,1)
   var firstday=now.getDay()
   var monthname=nameofmonth(month)
   var daysofmonth=monthdays(month,year)
    if(firstday>0)
      var k=-(firstday-1)
    else
      k=1
   var table="<table border=5 cellspacing=3cellpadding=8>"
   table +="<tr><th colspan=7>"+monthname + date+"th</th> <td  style='cursor:pointer' onclick='close()'>[close]</td></tr>"
   table +="<tr><th>sun</th><th>mon</th><th>tue</><th>wed</th><th>thu</th><th>fri</><th>sat</th></tr>"
   for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
     table+="<tr>"
     for(var j=0;j<7;j++)
      {
        if(k<=daysofmonth && k>0)
          { if(k==date)
             table+='<td id="clock" bgcolor="aqua">'+k+'</td>'
          else
           table+='<td style="cursor:pointer">'+k+'</td>'
           k=parseInt(k)

         }
      else
         table+="<td></td>"
         k++
       }
  table+="</tr>"
  document.getElementById("calender").innerHTML=table  
}
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onclick="table()"/>
<table id="container"><tr><td id="calender"></td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code of a calender which appears after clicking on a textbox.Here is a close cell in table.when close is clicked the close() function will called and calender will disappear.But this is not happening.why?please help me...thanks in advance..

Comment: Semicolons are good practice but irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the semicolons. Those are mostly optional and not needed in this example.
The function `close()` is reserved and cannot be called by `onclick`. Just rename `close()` to something like `closeCalendar()` and it should be working fine.

Comment: The solution is correct, but the explanation is a little off. It's not that it's reserved *(though it is used)*, but rather it's that there's also a `document.close` method, and since an inline handler has `document` in the scope chain before `window`, the `document.close` is shadowing the `window.close` in the variable scope lookup. If you change the inline handler to use `onclick='window.close()'`, then it will work, unless a browser happens to make `window.close` a non-writable property, which I would doubt.

Answer (score 1):

`close` is a `javascript Keyword` you should use another word other than `close` for your function name for more info check out [JavaScript Reserved Words](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ChtXh/) of how it could work more elegantly

```
<input type="text" id="cal" onclick="table(this)"/>
<div id="container">
    <div id="calender"></div>
</div>
```

```
function nameofmonth(month)  {  
  return ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"][month];
}  

function closeIt(){
  document.getElementById("container").style.display='none';
}

function table(cal) {
   var now=new Date(),
      hour=now.getHours(),
      minute=now.getMinutes(),
      second=now.getSeconds(),
      date=now.getDate(),
      month=now.getMonth(),
      year=now.getFullYear();
   now.setFullYear(year,month,1);
   var firstday=now.getDay(),
       monthname=nameofmonth(month);
   now.setFullYear(year,now.getMonth()+1,0); // last of this month
   var daysofmonth=now.getDate();
   var k=(firstday>0)?-(firstday-1):1;
   var table="<table border=5 cellspacing=3 cellpadding=8>"
   table +="<tr><th colspan=7>"+monthname + date+"th</th> <td  style='cursor:pointer' onclick='closeIt()'>[close]</td></tr>"
   table +="<tr><th>sun</th><th>mon</th><th>tue</><th>wed</th><th>thu</th><th>fri</><th>sat</th></tr>";
   for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
     table+="<tr>";
     for (var j=0;j<7;j++) {
       if (k<=daysofmonth && k>0) {
         if (k==date) table+='<td id="clock" bgcolor="aqua">'+k+'</td>';
         else table+='<td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.getElementById(\''+cal.id+'\').value=\''+(month+1)+'/'+k+'/'+year+'\'">'+k+'</td>';
       }
       else table+="<td></td>";
       k++
     }
     table+="</tr>";
    }     
    document.getElementById("calender").innerHTML=table+"</table>";  

}
```